# How many UITableView can place in a View?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I'm beginner in Iphone!
Can I place many UITableView (greater 1) in a View? And how to control them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well its not a good idea to have multiple tableviews in a view but if you want it you can have them and control the by there names like

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if(tableView == declaredTableView1){
return 10;
}
else if(tableView == declaredTableView2){
return 11;
}
else {
return 12;
}   
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You mean by the names of the outlet variables that refer to the table views, right?

Comment: @peter yes I do this in this way

Answer (score 1):

You can place as many UITableViews into a parent view, but it's probably not a good idea. Each delegate and datasource method for a tableView takes that tableView as its first argument, so it's easy to tell them apart.